# Do you need to upload your app to the app store before in-app purchases work?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I get errors when I try my IAP's in the simulator, it says "Purchase Failed: invalidProductId" but it returns the right ID that is setup in the store. Is this because I have not submitted my app (or binary, what is this?)?

Project is here: github.com/kaio37k/KCC

Comment: are you using a sandbox Apple id?

Comment: No, I don't have an Apple id setup with the simulator. Should I try that? If so, how do I log into the id on the simulator?

Comment: Apple has an extensive guide for in app purchase testing here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: Shouldn't it at least not return an error though? The IAP is not even setting up... I think a sandbox test account would only help if my issue was *buying* the product, my issue is that the product just says unavailable when I click on it.

Comment: Please post all the code you are using to try to complete your IAP test. There are too many factors to try to diagnose without all the info.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a paid pod so I cannot, but I can give you this much.
The purchaseID being tried *is* correct - the purchase dialog error says "*Could not retrieve product info:* Invalid product identifier: com.bsnsname.iap.iap1" - The error in the terminal says "Purchase Failed: Invalid Product ID" - the IAP's are saved on iTunes Connect in the same name as the error is returning - I have NOT uploaded my app or binary to iTunes Connect yet, despite this, it works for the teacher in the course I am following.

Comment: without code, I can't help. There are countless online resources to help learn how to properly set up IAP.

Comment: Yes, but I am using a wrapper with nearly no support. Can you tell me this: do I need to upload my project to iTunes connect before IAP's work? Or will they appear to work without uploading first?

Comment: Ok, I uploaded it to git: https://github.com/kaio37k/KCC

Comment: Have you tested on an actual device?  You cannot test IAP on the simulator

Comment: No, I have not. But as I said to BJHStudios, my instructor tested it on the simulator and it did not give any error.